# HBase REST API Scanner Lifetime

Tags: hadoop, hbase

According to the REST API documentation for HBase [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest).

I can use the API to create a scanner, scan some rows, and then delete the scanner. There's a line on the delete request that says:

```
Deletes the scanner and frees the resources it used.
```

So my question is: if I don't delete the scanner, what's the lifetime? Do they get cleaned up on their own? Do they ever get cleaned up? Can I effectively cache the scanner and keep using it until I get a 404 on the route?

My reason for asking this is to implement pagination on my app. The user gets the first X rows, and can click to the next page to get X more. Instead of nailing up and deleting a new scanner each time, it would be nice to cache the scanner references. But I'd like to know how long they're alive by default in order to properly configure my own scanner cache.

Comment: AFAIK there would be timeout configured. you can't open the connection forever. I'd suggest open new scanner for every rest request, once you are finished i.e after delete. For pagination, Solr(if you are using cloudera search) + Solrj is best as per my experience with it.

Comment: @RamPrasadG Yeah, I agree. Initial testing with using PUT-GET-DELETE on the scanner for every X rows I need to fetch is proving to be more than fast enough so far, I just want to be prepared in case that proves to be a bottleneck down the line.